# Division problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Problem statement

> Five sailors were cast away in an
>   island, inhabited only by monkeys. To
>   provide food, they collected all the
>   coconuts that they could find. During
>   the night, one of the sailors woke up
>   and decided to take his share of the
>   coconuts. He divided them into 5 equal
>   piles and noticed that one coconut was
>   left over, so he threw it to the
>   monkeys; he then hid his pile and went
>   to sleep. A little later a second
>   sailor awoke and had the same idea as
>   the first one. He divided the
>   remainder of the coconuts into 5 equal
>   piles, discovered also that one
>   coconut was left over, and threw it to
>   the monkeys. He then hid his share and
>   went back to sleep. One by one the
>   other three sailors did the same
>   thing, each throwing one coconuts to
>   the money. The next morning, all
>   sailors looking sharp and ready for
>   breakfast, divided the remaining pile
>   of coconuts into five equal parts, and
>   no coconuts was left over this time.
>   Find the smallest number of coconuts
>   in the original pile.

My solution was, each time a sailer take his share, I recalculate the number of coconut:

1. $n = 5\cdot q_0 + 1  $
   $\to$ # left = $\frac{4}{5}\cdot q_0 = \frac{4}{5}\cdot \frac{n - 1}{5}$
2. $\frac{4}{5}\cdot q_0 = 5 \cdot q_1 + 1 \to$ # left $= \frac{4}{5}\cdot q_1 ....$

Continuing this process, I ended up with a very strange fraction:

$$\frac{(256\cdot n - 464981)}{1953125}$$

Then I set this fraction to $5\cdot k$, since the last time # coconuts is divisible by $5$, to solve for $n$.
Am I in the right direction? Any hint would greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: Another monkey question!  Are we going to be seeing a "monkeys" tag soon?  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote that $n = 5q_0 + 1$, so then the first sailor threw away a coconut, and kept $q_0$ coconuts. **The remaining number of coconuts is $4q_0$!**

So then you write:

$$n = 5q_0 + 1$$
$$4 q_0 = 5q_1 + 1$$
$$4 q_1 = 5q_2 + 1$$
$$4 q_2 = 5q_3 + 1$$
$$4 q_3 = 5q_4 + 1$$
$$4 q_4 = 5q_5$$

Now you know that $q_5 > 0$, so $n$ will be smallest when $q_5 = 1$. (Of course if they had nothing for breakfast, do the following with $q_0 = 0$).

You must also consider that when the fifth sailor was taking his share, after throwing away a coconut, the remaining number of coconuts was divisible by $5$. So

$$ q_4 = \frac{5q_5}{4}$$

must be an integer. Let's write $q_5 = 4k_0$. Then writing the equations backwards, and expressing $q_3$ with $q_{4}$ yields:

$$4 q_4 = 5q_5 = 20k_0 \text{  so  } q_4 = 5k_0$$
$$4 q_3 = 5q_4 + 1 = 5^2k_0 +1 $$

Again you must make sure that $\frac{5^2k_0 +1}{4}$ is an integer. Continue on until you reach $n$. You will be reexpressing the $k_0$ from here on (that's why I added the subscript).

Comment: @milcak: Thanks a lot for your hint. I'm happy because this is the first time I feel like I was on track ^_^!

Comment: @Chan you probably even did the backwards direction correctly, but the mistake in the begginning created that nasty fraction. Try it now, if you need any additional hint let me know

Comment: @milcak: I ended up with this equation `256n - 5^6k0 = 2101`. Is it strange? Then now I have to solve for n in term of k0? I lost again :(.

Comment: What I meant to say, is that you have to establish what form $k_0$ is in order to have $\frac{5^2k_0 +1}{4}$ always an integer, for example $k_0 = ak_1 + b$ for some $a,b$. Then you will have $q_3$ equal to some expression containing $k_1$. Then you go up a step - get $q_2$ equal to some expression containing $k_2$ etc. In the end you will have $n$ equall to some expression containing $k_4$, then set $k_4 = 1$ to get the lowest number of coconuts.

Comment: @micak: Thanks again, but I don't understand how k4 = 1 will yield the least number of coconut. Could you explain this?

Comment: If $k_4$ is any positive integer, the whole division proccess will go as described. You will have that $n$ is an *increasing* function of $k_4$. So when $k_4 = 1$, the number of coconuts will be lowest.

Comment: @milcak: hm, I need to think more. Still don't get the logic. And when I set k0 = ak1 + b, is there any constraint on a, b except divisible by 4? For example I set k0 = 4k1 - 1, but I think there are many a, b.

Comment: You want the least $a,b$ here. So indeed $k_0 = 4k_1 -1$ or $k_0 = 4k_1 +3$ will work. I can finish the solution for you when I have time in a few hours (if you are interested).

Comment: @micak: Thank for your kindness ;) I got n = 18746. Does it seem right to you? I use 4k1 - 1. Could you explain how both `4k1 - 1` and `4k1 + 3` work? I think `4k1 - 1` is less than `4k1 + 3` right?

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a hint, so I won't give the full answer:

Step (1): Realize that if K is an answer, so is K + n*5^(5+1) for any n.
Step (2): The hint for this step will probably give the whole thing away so it is withheld
Step (3):

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not sure I understand your hint. You said: `K + n*5^(5+1) for any n`, this is not an equation, so how could I find K?